# Cypress: Lodash: Cypress._.sample flaky

Tags: javascript, cypress, lodash, dropdown

I have written this method but it is very flaky.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("selectRandomDropdownOption", function () {
  cy.get(".ng-option")
    .as("dropdownOptions")
    .should("be.visible")
    .then((options) => {
      Cypress._.sample(options).click({ force: true });
      cy.get("@dropdownOptions").should("not.exist");
    });
});
```

every second test fails because cypress says `Cypress._.sample(...).click` is not a function which makes no sense because sometimes the method works. Can you tell me why this is? Is it because of my code or lodash itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One explanation might be that `options` is sometimes empty when the `.click()` is attempted, due to loading latency.

Try adding a length check

```js
cy.get(".ng-option")
  .should("be.visible")
  .should('have.length','gt', 0)
  .then((options) => {
    Cypress._.sample(options).click();
  })
cy.get(".ng-option").should("not.exist")
```

---

**Converting to an array**

The problem is `options` is an object, not an array.

If you `console.log(options)` you'll see it has a couple of extra properties `prevObject` and `selector` which are sometimes selected by the randon function.

```js
jQuery.fn.init(2) [option, option, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1), selector: '.ng-option']
```

But these properties do not support the `.click()` function, and are not what you want to select anyway.

To fix, first convert the `options` object to an array

```js
cy.get(".ng-option")
  .should("be.visible")
  .should('have.length','gt', 0)
  .then((options) => {
    const optionsArray = [...options]
    Cypress._.sample(optionsArray).click();
  })
cy.get(".ng-option").should("not.exist")
```

Comment: with your code sometimes it works and sometimes it is no function or the code in the .then statement is not executed. thats weird.

Comment: So, no difference. You will need to `console.log(options)` and `console.log(Cypress._.sample(options))` to see what's going on.